# nHibernate and multiple tasks

Tags: nhibernate, concurrency, task

I am trying to improve performance of our nHibernate (3.3.2.4000) application (.NET 4.0). Currently, we are performing CRUD operations one by one, which ends up taking a lot of time, so my plan was to use the ConcurrentQueue and Tasks.

I refactored my code into this:

```
    public void ImportProductsFromXml(string path)
    {
        List<Product> products = Mapper.GetProducts(path);

        var addQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<Product>(productsToAddUpdate);
        var updateTasks = new List<Task>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            var taskId = i + 1;
            updateTasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ProcessAddQueue(taskId, products, addQueue)));
        }
    }

    private void ProcessAddQueue(int taskId, List<Product> products, ConcurrentQueue<Product> queue)
    {
        Product result = null;
        while (queue.TryDequeue(out result))
        {
            try
            {
                UpdateProducts(products, result);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("ProcessAddQueue: taskId={0}, SKU={1}, ex={2}", taskId, result.ProductId, ex));
            }
        }
    }

    private void UpdateProducts(List<Product> productsFromFile, Product product)
    {
        ...code removed...
            CatalogItem parentItem = _catalogRepository.GetByCatalogItemId(category);
        ...code removed...
            _catalogRepository.Save(parentItem);
        ...code removed...
    }

    public CatalogItem GetByCatalogItemId(string catalogItemId)
    {
        using (ISession session = SessionFactory.OpenSession())
        {
            return session
                .CreateCriteria(typeof (CatalogItem))
                .Add(Restrictions.Eq("CatalogItemId", catalogItemId))
                .List<CatalogItem>().FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
```

The "Save"-method of the catalogRepository calls this method, behind the scenes:

```
public int Add(T entity)
    {
        using (ISession session = SessionFactory.OpenSession())
        using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            var id = (int) session.Save(entity);
            transaction.Commit();
            return id;
        }
    }
```

So my idea was to create a concurrentqueue containing all the products, and then process them 5 at a time.

However, I am getting an 'Thread was being aborted exception':

```
at System.WeakReference.get_Target()
at System.Transactions.Transaction.JitSafeGetContextTransaction(ContextData contextData)
at System.Transactions.Transaction.FastGetTransaction(TransactionScope currentScope, ContextData contextData, Transaction& contextTransaction)
at System.Transactions.Transaction.get_Current()
at NHibernate.Transaction.AdoNetWithDistributedTransactionFactory.EnlistInDistributedTransactionIfNeeded(ISessionImplementor session)
at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.get_PersistenceContext()
at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.EntityIsTransient(SaveOrUpdateEvent event)
at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.OnSaveOrUpdate(SaveOrUpdateEvent event)
at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.FireSave(SaveOrUpdateEvent event)
at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Save(Object obj)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate sessions are meant to be used as unit of work. You open a session, open a transaction on it, load your entity, modify it, call save, commit/rollback the transaction and then dispose the session.

You should be using ONE session to load your entity and then save it. Currently you are loading an entity with one session and saving it with some other session. Combined with concurrent access this could cause problems.

Try loading and saving the entity with the same hibernate session.

When using hibernate as mentioned it should be fully threadsafe. Please note that a single hibernate session is NOT threadsafe.

Comment: I am looking into this suggestion, however it requires a lot of rewriting of my current repository. Currently, I am stuck with exceptions like "a-different-object-with-the-same-identifier-value-was-already-associated-with-a-different-session", but I will mark this as an answer when I have verfied if it works for me

Comment: @Hos It's just a guess. I think it could be the problem though.

Comment: my business logic has multiple trips to the DB before calling save on the repository. I guess that's why I get error about objects belonging to another session. Do you have any sample code for a scenario like this? I am using this approach for the rewrite of the repository: http://www.primaryobjects.com/2010/03/17/using-the-nhibernate-repository-pattern-in-c-asp-net/